# TexLive on Windows 10 - Error: pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

Tags: fonts, texlive, windows

I installed TexLive on windows 10. It was working well. But after moving to a new user on my Windows, I encounter the following error:

> name = IranNastaliq/OT, rootname = IranNastaliq/OT, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile! kpathsea: Running mktexmf IranNastaliq/OT.mf The command name is C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\mktexmf Cannot find IranNastaliq/OT.mf.

It is related to fonts. I checked my fonts, the font is installed.

How I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts must be installed for all users.

Right click on the font file, and choose `Install for all users` option.